# Hide Asp:DropDownList based on select dropdownlist values?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to hide two dropdownlists based on a value from the "Select" dropdownlist. The to ddlists i want to hide is the Asp:DropDownLists. The select class looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="number_rooms">
             <option>1</option>
             <option>2</option>
</select>
```

When the value is 1, the dropdownlists should be hidden.
When the value is 2, the users should see them.

**Code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="droplist1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>   
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="droplist2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Have tried some Jquery from former posts, but none seem to work..

**JQuery code:**

```
        $(function () {
            $("#number_rooms").change(function() {
                $("#droplist1").hide();
                $("#droplist2").hide();
            });
        });
```

Have also tried this:

```
        $(function () {
            if ($("#number_rooms").val() == 1) 
                $("#droplist1").hide();
                $("#droplist2").hide();
        });
```

The value is 1 at default, so at page loadup it should be hidden, and if a user select value = 2 , it should be shown.

Hope someone can see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: when your asp:dropdown gets rendered the id changes to include it's parents id, so you need to check whats the correct id or use <%= droplist1.ClientID %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your asp:DropDownList gets rendered its id changes to include the id of the container or containers

So your DropDownList could be rendering with an id like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="mycontainer_droplist1">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

You can get the correct Client ID by using

```
$("#<%= droplist1.ClientID %>").hide();
$("#<%= droplist2.ClientID %>").hide();
```

Or you can change the declaration of the asp:DropDownList to make its ID static and avoid having its container ids setting the [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) 
this its the default id generation

> The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_).

```
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="static" ID="droplist2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

> Static : The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

Comment: Thx for it.. ClientIDMode is a pain in the ass :)